# FInd an unused/empty space in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

again i encountered a problem while working on a project (next one, in class again).
I need to know how to find an unused space within an array in C# (Unity 3D)

I can provide further informations and code parts, i am willing to change my code in parts, but not to much, as i will get my grades(not a real grade, more  a rating-like thing) on how much i have done. (and yes, i am allowed to ask Questions in the web :P)

Thanks for your help in advance,
I (my real name makes an Error so i cant post o.O)

Comment: you need to know if there is any array index with empty value ?

Comment: traverse the array elements & check each on of them has values or not...

Comment: yes AccessDenied, you got the point

Comment: Ulaga, thats the point, as im pretty new and newbish to programming, i dont know how to do that. (only got told to be the scripter cause im not affraid of hourlong tutorials and searchin asnswers with google)

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work, please note, it's untested.

LINQ:

```
var nullOrEmptyIndexes = ListObject.Select((item, index) => new { item, index }).Where(x => x.item == null).Select(x => x.index);
```

Loops:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetEmptyIndexes(List<object> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] == null)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Change ListObject to the list you wish to check.

Although, you really shouldn't have blanks in your list, seems messy to me.

Comment: well, i think this is written in JS, right? or at least most of those commands are unknown to my Editor Oo
if this is written in JS, i have to beg for excuses, as im not versed enough to transfer non-basic code to C# =(

Comment: That's LINQ.  Hmmm, gimme a moment.

Comment: That method should take any list object and loop through for nulls, returning a list of integers which represent the indexes of each null/blank item. - Now I just hope Unity supports yield! :)

Comment: Okay, this looks pretty working to me, but i got an error. I know this is just my mistake, but may you would correct this Line for me:

public static IEnumerable<int> GetEmptyIndexes(List<NoteStorage> list)

where as NoteStorage is an 2Darray, and it is the array that needs to be itterated through. Where do i have to replace my things in this Code?

Comment: You would only change 'GetEmptyIndexes(NoteStorage list)' and then you could loop through your array inside (already done for you).  You didn't mention it was a 2d array though, you would need to return two ints though, one for the x and y respectively though right?

Comment: naa, x is already set, i just need to know which storypart (numbered) will be on which place in the inventory/logbook (they wont be sorted, if you fund note 5 first it will stay on place 1 in your inventory till everything gets deleted). and well, jeah, this with the 2D i forgot to mention (slowly going crazy about this all^^)

Comment: If X is already set then just pass in the y part of the array and you'll get back a list of blank y indexes :)